# Which content security policy header settings are compatible with Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client, security

Reading up on Content Security Policy (CSP) headers, there are a few that look like they might break the Sitecore Content Editor and Experience Editor, if implemented on the Content Management server.

What are the strongest (most restrictive) security settings for CSP that allow a fully functioning Sitecore client?

https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#content-security-policy

Comment: I've used `upgrade-insecure-requests` without issue. The setting `blocked-all-mixed-content` breaks the Workbox for sure.

Comment: Sitecore has added [a KB article for CSP](https://kb.sitecore.net/Articles/2019/03/05/09/51/464569.aspx) which states: _the CSP definition for Content Management (CM) instance should definitely allow `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` scripts for the mapped CM hostname(s)_

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to break Sitecore itself; it depends on how restrictive you want to be.

I've found that I have to allow unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval for script, and most other media needs to be "self"

The project I'm working on currently uses the following (it's quite loose - lots of media from other domains):

```
default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; script-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' [remove various analytics] ; connect-src * ; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;
```

Seems to work okay, but you might want something more restrictive.

If so, a good option then would be to turn on your CSP in Report-Only mode. Set a policy something like:

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;
```

Use a service such as [report-uri.com](https://report-uri.com/) to record violations (or just monitor the console in Chrome's DevTools), and try using it for a while. Once you've got some violations, review, and adjust your policy.

Comment: Yes, we're planning on using report-only for some of the more tricky parts, and obviously what we can implement on content delivery is dependent on solution requirements. These are things that can be designed or refactored though. I'm mainly interested in the Sitecore content management server, as this isn't something we can recode.